# How can I stop slicex from taking out the channel settings?

Tags: sampling, fl-studio

Everytime I sample something using edison change the pitch in channel settings etc. and throw it in Slicex, Slicex interprets the sample in it's raw format. Is there a better way of stopping Slicex from doing this other than saving the sample in it's current state and re-adding it to Slicex ?